# Deleting Message cache

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

Trying to delete all SMS and iMessage cache.  Other forums and research indicates a SYNC will do this.  Have tried, but old messages keep showing up in Spotlight search.  I want them deleted for good.  How?

Answer (score -2):

Obviously, it’s a cache bug (or more like feature). If you find that it’s a little annoying, Apple does provide a way to remove this.

Here’s how to delete recent contacts from messages app (and other apps in iOS):

- Go to the Messages app and tap on the New Message icon
- In the recipient field, tap the name of the recently-deleted contact (or a part of the number)
- When the contact shows up in the list, you should see a blue ‘i’ icon right next to the contact you just deleted
- Tap on the ‘i’ icon. Next, tap on Remove from Recents
- That’s about it. The contact will no longer show up.

It’s really that simple. This will remove the contact from the cache (of recent contacts) and it will make sure that the deleted contact doesn’t show up anywhere in iOS.

The problem doesn’t appear for contacts that you have not communicated with (via Email, Message or FaceTime). It’s mostly for contacts that you have communicated with via these services. The Recent Contacts list holds a cache of contact data (contacts that you have recently talked/messaged to) and it’s not available to modify.

Comment: The issue was not about contacts. -1